# How to store user actions in MeteorJs using MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, mongodb, meteor

I'm using Meteor JS for a project so inherently I'm using MongoDB. I'm storing a user's check in and out actions. I'm currently storing them as individual docs in the collection. Each action contains 3 fields; in or out, time of action and userid. Is the best way to go though? Should I just have one doc per members and then store each action in an array? Is there another way? I anticipate several hundred members, but hopefully several thousands of members in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I can say that storing records instead of arrays is a better choice in the long run.

As far as Meteor is concerned, its reactivity handles collection records, but not individual fields in arrays. In other words, if one element gets added to the `checkins` array of a user object, the entire user object needs to be synchronized with the clients. If you store records instead, only the newly added record will be sent by the publication.

As far as MongoDB is concerned, there is a document size limit of 16MB. Not sure how frequent your checkins and checkouts are, but if you store them in an array, you might run into that limitation at some point.

Records are also easier to access than arrays.

For more details, see [MongoDB data modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) and [Database modeling](https://bulletproofmeteor.com/database-modeling/one-many-relationships) in Bulletproof Meteor.